# encapsulation of objects in java

Tags: java, methods, entity, encapsulation

Good afternoon everyone.

I was thinking about some question in Java. All companies that i worked till now never bother themselves with a good and encapsulate code. Cause this i made this question in my own head.

What's the better and subtle way to solve the old problem of atualize some object.

Create anemics entities with getters and setters (without verification) or pass the same object as parameter and the new values of their atributes following it.

Ex:

anemics entities:

```
public class RenterGrouping implements Serializable {

    private Integer idRenterGrouping;
    private String name;
public RenterGrouping() {
}

public RenterGrouping(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "idRenterGrouping", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getIdRenterGrouping() {
    return idRenterGrouping;
}


@Column(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setIdRenterGrouping(Integer idRenterGrouping) {
    this.idRenterGrouping = idRenterGrouping;
}


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Or the second way instead (without setters):

```
public class RenterGrouping implements Serializable {

private Integer idRenterGrouping;
private String name;

public RenterGrouping() {
}

public RenterGrouping(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public RenterGrouping updateRenterGrouping(RenterGrouping renterGrouping, Integer idRenterGrouping, String name) {
    renterGrouping.idRenterGrouping = idRenterGrouping != null? idRenterGrouping : null;
    renterGrouping.name = name != null? name : null;

    return renterGrouping;

}


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "idRenterGrouping", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getIdRenterGrouping() {
    return idRenterGrouping;
}


@Column(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

The import fact here is protect the object and their atributes.

Someone else agre with the method **updateRenterGrouping**?

waiting your feedbacks guys.
Thank you guys!

Comment: So you want to have a single method with possibly dozens of parameters that would update none, some or all of the values in the object? Wouldn't pass my code review.

Comment: Aren't the conditional operators unnecessary?

Comment: anemics does not exist in my dictionary (except maybe referring to anemia, an illness due to lack of blood or blood cells...). Please clarify the term as related to java classes.

Answer (score 0):

Look the method that is calling the entity:

```
public RenterGroupingTO saveOrUpdate(Integer idRenterGrouping, String name) throws Throwable {

    RenterGrouping renterGrouping;

    if (idRenterGrouping != null && idRenterGrouping != 0) {
        renterGrouping = getById(idRenterGrouping);
        renterGrouping = renterGrouping.updateRenterGrouping(renterGrouping, idRenterGrouping, name); // calls the method

    } else {

        renterGrouping = new RenterGrouping(name);
    }

    FactoryDAO.getInstance().getRenterGroupingDAO().saveOrUpdate(renterGrouping);
    return new RenterGroupingTO(renterGrouping);
}
```

it perserve ourselves to do something like:

```
renterGrouping = getById(idRenterGrouping);
renterGrouping.setIdRenterGrouping(idRenterGrouping);
renterGrouping.setName(name);
```

**Kayaman**
supposing that we have 10 parameters, same this way we just have to call the updateRenterGrouping(parameters...) method instead create 10 setters into entity and worse in every place that we want to input values in these atributes.
Another possibilitie is: Instead create entity.setAtribute(x) for every atribute anywhere, we've the method that do it for us.

does not it worth??

Comment: If you want to save on code, you can achieve awesome savings with introspection; however, you will lose compile-time sanity checks. Before using introspection to set fields, I would recommend making the fields public and calling a single "persist()" method. On the other hand, most IDEs can generate getters/setters for you automatically. Yes, it is boilerplate; but it is not /that/ expensive.